# How to show as column to recursive rows in a table With SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table like this:

```
patientId                   Code
------------------------    ----
ChNOu1fny0ve2N4AeCcxqw==    G309
ChNOu1fny0ve2N4AeCcxqw==    I260
wFgf4sgQ3VZyFiKXlHnKdw==    Z380
wFgf4sgQ3VZyFiKXlHnKdw==    1130600
```

I want to show `patientId` in one row with patient's codes. Sql output should like this:

```
patientId                   Code1   Code2
------------------------    -----   --------
ChNOu1fny0ve2N4AeCcxqw==    G309    I260
wFgf4sgQ3VZyFiKXlHnKdw==    Z380    1130600
```

How can we do this with SQL Server?

Thanks

Comment: How `G309` and `Z380` is under `code1` why not `G309` and `1130600`. There should be another column which should define the relation

Comment: Because every patient Id Have spesific codes.

Comment: Is every code unique in the table? If not you can pivot it.

Comment: @coder3 How you are segregating `code1` why this `1130600` code didn't come under `code1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `pivot` to do this.

```
SELECT patientId,[code1],[code2]
FROM  (SELECT *,
              'code'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Row_number() OVER(partition BY patientId ORDER BY (select null) )) piv_col
       FROM   Tablename) a
      PIVOT (Max(Code)
            FOR piv_col IN ([code1],
                            [code2])) piv
```

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39b4e/1)